# Automatically sorted DIVs?

Tags: css, html

Not sure how to describe this easily in the title!

I need to have dynamically generated divs (which I'm doing in php) which will be placed like blocks within another div. This container div will be sized depending on the window size, but the blocks will be of fixed size. Is there a way in CSS to make it do this, or will I have to be clever with js?

I did create a diagram, but can't post it with my lack of reputation :/

I hope this makes sense to someone...

Comment: just paste the URL to an example image. If that doesn't work replace dots etc. with (DOT)

Comment: @Nick Husler: lol... deadly title :D

Comment: Hehe yeah, not sure what I was thinking, but it was before my first coffee of the day ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

HTML:

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="block"></div>
  <div class="block"></div>
  <div class="block"></div>
  <br class="clear"/> <!-- if you want horiz layout -->
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.container
{
  width: 100%;
}

.block
{
  width: 100px; /* change to be whatever fixed width you want */
  float: left; /* if you want horiz layout*/
}

.clear { clear:both; } /* for horiz layout */
```

Is this along the lines of what you mean?

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure what exactly you want but still created a [**Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/LC25e/)

```
.container {
    width:100%; float:left;
    background:red;
}
.child {
    width:40px; height:40px; float:left; margin:5px; background:blue;
}

<div class="container">
    <div class="child"></div>
    <div class="child"></div>
    <div class="child"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you both. I'm still teaching myself this stuff so there may be a few more basic questions where this came from. This is just what I needed :)

Comment: You cant even upvote my answer .. :( .. anyways keep learning.